# Email body content translation issue in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, translation, email-verification

hello all in my laravel app I have language translation option. English and French.

So In my `lang` folder I have `en` and `fr` folders. Each folder I have a file called, `sentence.php` where I store my translation array.

Sample code as follows,

```
en>sentence.php

<?php

// sentence.php

return [
  'welcome' => 'Welcome',

fr>sentence.php
<?php

// sentence.php

return [
  'welcome' => 'Bienvenue ',
```

Normally I display my translations in my views like this

```
{{ __('sentence.Welcome') }}
```

**THE ISSUE**

Now guys my issue is, I'm sending an custom email to my users with some activation instructions. And I'm failing to translate that email using my regular method.

```
public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        return (new MailMessage)
                    ->line(''.('sentence.We have successfully created your user account').'')
                   
                    ->line(''.('sentence.Thank you for joining with us!').'');
                    
    }
```

out put of this first line is,

```
sentence.We have successfully created your user account
```

How can I translate this properly, what i'm doing wrong?

I'm using laravel 7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just shooting from the hip:

```
public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        return (new MailMessage)
                    ->line( __('sentence.We have successfully created your user account'))
                   
                    ->line( __('sentence.Thank you for joining with us!'));
                    
    }
```

But this doesn't seems to be Laravel mail for me. Lara has a very nice mailbuilder out of the box (Markdown) which you can build from components, and also you can send raw mails.

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/mail#markdown-mailables